# Replace a huge amount of strings in many documents

Tags: node.js

I am having the issue that I want to clone a huge dataset (around 500.000 documents) in a NoSQL database. Each of these documents is having an ID (usually something like a uuid/objectID). however, while copying the documents, each document gets a new ID. I am saving this in a dict/map: `mapping[oldId] = newId`

The ID of most of this documents might be part of other documents, in the best case as a complete string (e.g. `parentDocument: "<someid>"`), but sometimes it might be a substring (e.g. `content: "See our other <a href='/<someid>'>Document</a>`.

**How can I somehow efficiently replace all those occurrences** of multiple IDs in all those documents?

My Idea was to stringify the Document to JSON or EJSON and then do the replacement there, however, I would be still replacing thousands of strings.

Comment: Which NoSQL database? Can't you just dump & load into the new one?

Comment: It will stay in the same database. We use MongoDB. We just create another almost excactly copy of the data, except the IDs must be different.